# Need to get current path of my created dll class library

Tags: c#, asp.net, activex

I can't get the currently path of my created dll class library, which is loaded as an ActiveX in a ASP.NET web site.

I have tried several commands, but no success. For example, I tried to get current path in variable _path:

```
namespace WebScanControl {

    [ApplicationControl(Width=640,Height=480)]
    public sealed partial class ScanControl:ApplicationControl {

        public ScanControl() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void Construct(ReadOnlyCollection<object> args) {
            try {

                string _path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);


            } catch(Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{1}{0}{2}", Environment.NewLine, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace), ex.GetType().Name, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            base.Construct(args);
        }

     }
}
```

However, variable _path gets:

```
C:\Users\miyahira\AppDataLocalTemp\3f3574554-2ef8-e8r9-9c8b-e40561d03bb
```

Which is not its path.

The current path of my dll class library is:

```
F:\webapp\WebScan\Scan\
```

As you see, this class library is an ApplicationControl. Is that the reason why it's not possible to get its current path?

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you are thinking that the library will stay on the disk.

ASP.NET during the start up get's all the assemblies, and moves it to the temporary folder, where it can use them as it wants.

So the `C:\Users\miyahira\AppDataLocalTemp\3f3574554-2ef8-e8r9-9c8b-e40561d03bb` is a correct path.

How does your ActiveX component being add to the Application? And what is the location of the ASP.NET site? You can try to get the path from the [`HTTPContext.ApplicationInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.applicationinstance.aspx) property, but can't say for sure will it work or not.